# how to remove some node for xml?

Tags: python, xml, awk

there's a XML file contains content like

```
    <node1>
      bla
      <remove>
        abc
      </remove>
        kkk
    </node1>
```

I need to delete node  under node1, but there's some node like `<node9>` also contains `<remove>`, which should not be deleted, I want to know to to do it, may be awk script or Python or whatever.

the output should be

```
   <node1>
      bla
        abc
        kkk
    </node1>
```

Answer (score 3):

you should know that using text processing to to modify xml has risk. If you have to do it,  this sed one-liner should work for **your example and example in sudo's answer**:

```
sed '/node1>/,/node1>/{/remove>/d}' file
```

Comment: +1, if the tags are on single lines as described this is a nice approach.

Answer (score 2):

Using the following input:

```
$ cat file
<node1>
   bla
   <remove>
     abc
   </remove>
   kkk
</node1>
<node9>
   bla
   <remove>
     abc
   </remove>
   kkk
</node9>
```

The following script will remove the required tag using `GNU awk`:

```
$ awk '/<node1>/{gsub(/<[/]?remove>/," ")}
       {printf "%s%s",$0,RT}' RS='</node[0-9]+>' file | grep '\S'
<node1>
   bla
     abc
   kkk
</node1>
<node9>
   bla
   <remove>
     abc
   </remove>
   kkk
</node9>
```

The script will even do the job if tags are not found on a single line:

```
$ cat file
<node1>bla<remove>abc</remove>kkk</node1>
<node9>bla<remove>abc</remove>kkk</node9>

$ awk '/<node1>/{gsub(/<[/]?remove>/," ")}
       {printf "%s%s",$0,RT}' RS='</node[0-9]+>' file 
<node1>bla abc kkk</node1>
<node9>bla<remove>abc</remove>kkk</node9>
```

Comment: You should point out that this only works in `gwak`, since `RS` is more than one character.

Comment: @Jotne yes, I original meant to, must have got distracted.

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`

```
awk '/node1>/,/\/node1>/ {if ($0~/remove>/) $0=""} NF'
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a `xml` parser. In [python](/questions/tagged/python) a good one is `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'), 'xml')

for elem in soup.node1.children:
    if elem.name == 'remove':
        elem.decompose()

print(soup)
```